# How to access firstLevelModuleDependencies of a subproject from parent build.gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a gradle project with one sub-project named "Implementation", now in parent `build.gradle` I want to iterate on sub-project's first level dependencies, to achieve this I have added one task in `Implementation` sub-project as below:

```
tasks.register("getAllFirstLevelDependencies") {
    ext {
        deps = configurations.default.resolvedConfiguration.firstLevelModuleDependencies
    }
}
```

Now in parent project's `build.gradle` file I am calling this task by using code `var implProjectDependencies = (Set<ResolvedDependency>) tasks.getByPath(":Implementation:getAllFirstLevelDependencies").deps` which will give me all first level resolved dependencies.

But, I am looking a way in which I could able to access sub-project's first level dependencies without adding a task in sub-project's build.gradle. Something like in `build.gradle` of parent project:

```
project(":Implementation").configurations.resolvedConfiguration.firstLevelModuleDependencies
```

But, this line of code in parent `build.gradle` gives me error as

> Could not get unknown property 'resolvedConfiguration' for configuration container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer.

Is there anyway to do it?